# UITableview Search Bar: filtering arrays

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, filtering, uisearchbar

i have a problem with using a search bar filter for my UITableView.

I'm logging Temperature data in multiple arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *timeArray; // Array which saves date and time
NSMutableArray *tempInside; // saves inside temp
NSMutableArray *tempOutside; // saves outside temp
NSMutableArray *timeArraySearch; // Array which saves date and time searched
NSMutableArray *tempInsideSearch; // saves inside temp searched
NSMutableArray *tempOutsideSearch; // saves outside temp searched
```

So to display the all the data, i have a UITableView. I use the timeArray for the `cell.textlabel.text`.

Right now i have trouble with getting the data filtered using the search bar. Here is my 
`filterContentForSearchText` method:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    tempInsideSearch = [tempInside filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    tempOutsideSearch = [tempOutside filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    timeArraySearch = [timeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

I ran the application and got a empty array exception. Then i checked this method again and realized that its normal that the tempInsideSearch and tempOutsideSearch are empty, because they don't contain values like "06:41PM" ...

So finally here is my question:
How can i filter the temp arrays, that they fit the index with the timeArray?

Comment: Why do you so many arrays? Why not have one main array that stores all of the data and one array that stores the search results? Each element in the array should be an object or dictionary that has the time, and two temps.

Comment: hello, i don't know how to use the dictionary. so do you mean two arrays for example: `*dataArray, *searchArray`and inside those arrays i should store the other arrays as objects?

Comment: No, do not store the other arrays in `dataArray`. `dataArray` should contain a set of `NSDictionary` (or a custom object). Each dictionary would store a date/time, inside temp, and outside temp. This keeps each set of data together as a unit.

Comment: Do know know where i can find an easy NSDictionary Description/Tutorial/Example ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with date/time, insideTemp, outsideTemp properties, store instances of it into an array, and apply the filtering on that array instead of using 3 different arrays to store informations highly tied ...